# I'm trying to discard a bootstrap modal using Angular 6 when the server receives the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Well, this is the component where I'm trying to create all the content. It is a crud that saves the data when and what I want is for the modal to disappear.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="table-title">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Codigos De <b>Acceso.</b></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a href="#addProductModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Agregar nuevo codigo</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-12 pull-right d-flex flex-row-reverse'>
        <div id="custom-search-input">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGroupAddon2"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='clearfix'></div>
      <hr>
      <div id="loader"></div>
      <div id="resultados"></div>
      <div class='outer_div'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Modal HTML  -->
  <div id="addProductModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form #dataForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addData(dataForm)">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Codigo</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="dismiss" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Código</label>
              <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" #code="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.code" required >

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Dirección</label>
              <input type="text" name="direction" class="form-control" #direction="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.direction" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Comentario</label>
              <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" #comment="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.comment" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tech #</label>
              <input type="number" name="tech" class="form-control" #tech="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.tech" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar datos">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
```

and this is my ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Data } from '../../models/data' // La ruta puede ser distinta.
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datas',
  templateUrl: './datas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datas.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class DatasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  addData(form: NgForm) {
    this.dataService.postData(form.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.resetForm(form);

      })
  }

  /*
  close(form?: NgForm){
    if
  }*/

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form){
      form.reset();
      var dismiss = document.querySelector('#addProductModal');
      console.log(dismiss);
      this.dataService.selectedData = new Data();
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, that last method is called resetForm, I tried to clean the form when the data is sent and I have achieved it, but what I need is that the modal is discarded. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalhide

Comment: @Jota.Toledo that´s jQuery, I need Angular

Comment: You realize that currently you are working with jquery, right? Anyway, you could either try to trigger the click of the modal dismiss button or use an angular wrapper around bootstrap like ngb-bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM uninstall jQuery right away. Don't use the JavaScript version of bootstrap, install ngx-bootstrap and use the Angular components. They play much nicer with Angular. Your component should not be inspecting the DOM with querySelector and you shouldn't use any jQuery. If you rewrite the component using ngx-bootstrap you will be able to get an instance of an Angular modal component and call close.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try.